# Material design CSS framework that supports IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, material-design

I've used Materialize CSS in the past and I really like the framework. However a lot of our projects require IE9 support which Materialize doesn't support. Could anyone recommend a similar framework (preferable responsive, mobile first) they might have used in the past which supports IE9.

I've looked at Google's [MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/) which has 'B' support for IE9. but I'm looking for something which even if has a subset of features, does fully support IE9.

Comment: What features are you looking for?

Comment: A basic toolset which adheres to good design guidelines. Examples would be [this](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) and [this](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html) (except 'non-basic' things like cards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the material design aspects, then there are plenty of good frameworks out there with good legacy support.

If you want a material design look and feel, then these are your two choices. Obviously, MDL is the better choice, since it's fully supported by Google. AFAIK, the "B" in support for IE9 relates to features like "waves" radiating out when you press on a button. It does not mean anything breaks; it means some (gratuitous) features will degrade (gracefully), or not function.

Users of older browsers need to understand that refusing to update their browsers comes with a cost. Where do you draw the line? Do you support IE6? IE7? IE8? One survey shows IE9 with a market share of 2%. To what lengths are you willing to go to give those 2% of people some kind of amazing animated input box experience?

I understand that sometimes these decisions are made not by us wise developers, but by business people who operate under, shall we say, a different set of priorities. If that's the situation, the easiest way to get through to them is simply give them an estimate of two person-years for IE9 support.

Comment: Thank you for that. And your guess is right, it is a business decision. However, it's somewhat justified on the client's part because the computers they use also host other windows applications that don't support 'newer' operating systems (which is necessary to get the new IE versions). So, two person-years becomes a trivial amount of money when compared to upgrading a large subset of the IT infrastructure.

Comment: And these business people really think it's critical for the IE9 users to have cool transitions and spinning wheels?

Comment: Sorry, no. That's me.

But to explain further I'm not looking for cool transitions and spinning wheels. I just like the design principles of flat/material design. It's emphasis on minimal(ish) elements, and the way they use colours, icons and typography. The transitions etc. are just an added bonus for newer browsers.

Comment: As I mentioned, all the design elements **are** there in IE9. What the "B" means is you don't get the animations and other visual effedts.

Comment: It's actually not just 'graceful degradation' as they say and it's not just the absence of animation and other visual effects. For e.g. try rendering [this](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#buttons-section) page in IE9. This is the buttons component. You won't even see the + - icons inside the buttons. That practically renders the buttons useless, doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm, that's a nasty problem. But I'm confused--the plus is merely an MD icon, invoked by a harmless `<i class="material-icons">plus</i>`. That class pulls in the Material Icons font, and selects the code point from "plus" using a ligature-style mechanism (`-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';`). That CSS (in "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons") seems wrong for IE, which apparently doesn't take a vendor prefix. Try adding the rule `font-feature-settings: 'liga';` and see how far you get.

Comment: torazaburo, thanks for your comments. I think I'm gonna pass on MDL for now. The whole idea was to have something that supports IE9 oob, albeit with a reduced feature set. It's this kind of hacks and workarounds that I want to avoid in the interest of being nice to fellow devs who might inherit the project from me.

Comment: Sure, but that's sort of sad, because I like it and think it's solid and will be among the better maintained projects in the world. If this is the only hack required to get it to work it could still be worth it. Meanwhile, I've raised this issue: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1712.

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/179

Answer (score 1):

Try [Bootstrap Material Design](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/). Bootstrap itself supports IE9. But I don't guarantee a full 100% support. The market share of IE9 is so small that no one will make something fully compatible with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Saying no one will make something IE9 compatible, I feel, is an odd generalisation when there are lots of frameworks out there that do. And I did look at this framework actually, but it is only actively tested in IE11+, not even IE10.

Comment: I said fully compatible ;) IE is not a great browser to use, more and more developers tend to just "block" their websites from IE (and tell you to install chrome/firefox) rather to support it (except banks and gov sites).